# randomly deleting entries in a matrix in R

Tags: r, subset, missing-data

Does anyone know how to randomly delete or subset entries in a matrix in R?
For example, I would like to randomly delete the entries given miss in the code below. When I ran it gave A[4,2] and A[3,3]. I would really like to avoid a for loop because the real matrix I am working with is much bigger.

```
A=matrix(1:15, 5,3)
  nmiss=2
  obs=outer(1:nrow(A),1:ncol(A), FUN='paste', sep=',')
  miss=sample(obs,nmiss, replace=TRUE)
```

Unfortunately

```
 A[miss]=NA
```

doesn't work

Comment: First: `miss` is a character string, see it with `class(miss)`, of course it does not work with subsetting operators!!; Second: you want to delete row ok that I get it, but by "random", you mean delete rows randomly no matter what rows you delete?

Answer (score 3):

```
A[sample(nrow(A)*ncol(A), nmiss)] <- NA
```

You don't have to use row and column indices to subset a matrix randomly.